# Magento2 Site is quick but checkout takes over 1m to submit

Tags: magento2, checkout, performance

I've been working on a Magento2 site for a while now. and the entire site is quick, responsive, and working well in production mode. 
We work with Redis, and all caching on.

But when I place an order, this process takes over 1minute in load time. I even had to set the apache time-outs higher to not trigger a 503 error.

Is this a familiar issue. We don't have extensions running. 
Running on stable 2.1 and only did several design and layout modifications. Also on the normal theme, it's slow.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the site in production mode, as well? And what is your general stack, it can all make a difference.

But if its just the checkout, probably some loop somewhere going too long, you could use strace or a profiler to see that.

Comment: Yes it's in production. It's a php7 lemp stack at digital ocean. 2 CPU 6gb memory. Now other visitors on the site then me.

Comment: Try stracing it and see if anything loops, depending on your stack some command like this would be - ps auxw | grep php-fpm | awk '{print"-p " $2}' | xargs strace -s 1000 -e trace=sendto,connect,open,write -s 1000

Comment: Also make sure you don't have merged CSS enabled.